List SKUs based on Stock Location
I have a spreadsheet I want to automate, I have a list of SKUs and their stock locations, some SKUs are in multiple locations. I have a table with all the data in (Full MB52 tab), then I need one table for location 1 with the SKU, the quantity of stock in that location and the value of the stock, and one table for locations 5 and 7.

I could do just for Location 1 by sorting the column by Location and using
=IF('Full MB52'!D2="0001",'Full MB52'!A2,"")
But that only works for one location and requires sorting.

This is the table I want to fill in automatically with the SKUs for locations 5 and 7
I've tried vlookups and if formulas but without any luck

Why not use a pivot table? Else you can use FILTER function or INDEX/AGGREGATE depending on your Excel version.

This formula uses CHOOSEROWS and TOCOL functions
=CHOOSEROWS(A1:F5,TOCOL(IF((D1:D5="0005")+(D1:D5="0007"),ROW(D1:D5),1/0),3))


If you have a single table with the information from the first image, your best solution is likely to do a pivot table. This allows you to filter and refresh the information as new information becomes available and not need to maintain formulas. This is especially powerful if it's in a table format (CTRL + T) to convert your table to a table object.
But if you highlight the table with the data you're looking for and under the data tab of excel insert a pivot table. Bring in the column headers you want on the bottom left square of the fieldlist and the values you want measured (value, etc) into the bottom right.
Now, for formatting it to look more like a table. You will likely want to do to the "Design" tab of the ribbon (make sure you have the pivot table selected) and under "Report Layout", show in tabular form and repeat all item labels.
From here you're able to filter the location column to only include the locations you want. You can also add a slicer where you can control this as a floating button you can place elsewhere in the spreadsheet.
